# URL-Manager will not route

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I cloned our repositorie and created excatly the same URL-rules like at my own project. Now, i will get error like this after having logged in:

```
Firefox:
Fehler: Umleitungsfehler
The website called is rerouting request,which never will come to an end.
This problem sometimes occures, if cookies are deactivated

Chrome:
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

**I definetly accepted using cookies at both browser!!**
Debugging shows me,that I have dozen of 302-Requests,so Yii breaks down!
I use Windows, not LINUX, so I don't care about any permissions.
Here are the rules:

```html
    'urlManager' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => true,
                'enableStrictParsing' => true,
                'rules' => [
                    '/' => 'site/login',
                    'home' => 'site/index',
                    'logout' => 'site/logout',
                    'contact' => 'site/contact',
                    'signup' => 'site/signup',
                    'reset' => 'site/request-password-reset',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<action:(contact|captcha)>' => 'site/<action>'
                ],
```

Here is frontend configuration:

```html
<?php

$config = [
    // LZA 17-07-30 
    'sourceLanguage' => 'de-DE',
    'language' => 'de-DE',
    // LZA 17-07-30 siehe  Funktionen in  http://demos.krajee.com/grid#module    
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => '4lD2RxDNkC4ckpwxTmkDzOLIvk0JMs3F',
        ],
    ],
];

if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // LZA 17-07-30 CRUD
        'generators' => [// customized CRUD generator
            'crud' => [
                // 'class' => 'app\myCrud\crud\Generator', // LZA 17-07-20 die Klasse von CRUD generator
                'class' => '\common\wsl_dev\wsl_crud\crud\Generator', // LZA 17-07-20 die Klasse von CRUD generator
                'templates' => [
                    'myCrud' => '/@common/wsl_dev/wsl_crud/crud/default', //LZA 17-07-20 Templatename und Templatepfad
                ]
            ]
        ],
            // LZA 17-07-30 CRUD        
    ];
}

return $config;
```

If I deacitvate URLManger,setting

```
 'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
```

everything works fine.
If I put in manually Url like this:

```
http://localhost/yii2_perswitch/frontend/web/yiic.php/home
```

everything works fine,too

Any ideas,how to fix this? 
I deleted all my cookies,without any effects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Enable debug mode from web/index.php (uncomment these two lines):

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

and you can see exactly what causes the problem.

> Redirected too many times error was because the 777 permissions for
>   runtime and assets folder were not set.

**Solution 2:**

I think that the problem is related with the path or domain of the cookie. I believe that this info could be useful.

https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/cookies.md

Comment: I use Windows,so i don't need any permissions. Cookies are defined in both,frontend and backend(see above)